# Solution Object Record Type Permissions by Profile?

Tags: community

We have a requirement to create different record types under Solution object and give access to specific profile to those record type.

Setting as of now :

- Profile A - Object access (RCE) , Record type access (A1)
- Profile B - Object access (RCE) , Record type access (A1 , A2)

But problem is users from Profile A have access to record having record type A2.
They cannot create new of type A2 but they have read/edit access for A2 type.

Answer (score 1):

Profiles determine what a user can do with an object, it does not say which objects are visible to which users. For that you must use Organization Wide Defaults (OWD) and Sharing Settings. I suggest you take a look at the Salesforce video series "Who sees what" to explore the relationships between OWD, Sharing Settings and Profiles. It can take some time before you understand the subtleties, it is not the easiest Salesforce subject, but certainly one of the most important.

Having said that, the Solution object is special, in the sense that there is no OWD setting for Solutions. All Solution objects are visible to all users.

Comment: i am aware of OWD and Sharing settings, but here problem is we dont have entry for "Solution" in OWD or in sharing rule.   Can you please tell me if i am missing something else.

Comment: Well, yes, you are missing the Solution entry in OWD. As is everyone else, it's just not there. Solutions are "special", they are visible to all users, sorry, I overlooked that part of your question. What exactly are you trying to achieve? You are aware of this document? http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/0/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_solutions_implementation_guide.pdf

Comment: Yes, I have gone through this document. what all we implemented here is similar to the SFDC doc.. Now what we want is to restrict access for certain types. For that we created Record types and assigned to profiles. But problem is, records are still visible to all profiles irrespective of Recordtype assignment.

Comment: I have added a line about Solutions, in my answer, to reflect the remarks.